# What is the right way to branch and push new features to branch and the development branch in Git?

Tags: git, branch

i find it confusing to use branches in Git. Lets say we have a development branch called `Dev`.

Say i added a new feature and i made a new branch called `feature/user-can-logout`

What i usually do is:

```
git fetch origin
git fetch origin feature/user-can-logout
git checkout feature/user-can-logout
git add --all
git commit -m "message here"
git push origin feature/user-can-logout
git checkout Dev
git pull origin Dev
"Fix merge conflicts if any"
git merge feature/user-can-logout
```

Is this the right way to use branches and push the new features or is there something i'm missing? I want the project's commit history to be as perfect as possible.

Comment: That's it mate it look really good. If you are a beginner with Git, there is an IDE called "SourceTree", I think github had an IDE also. But the point with the IDE is that your branch are shown as a graphic. So it can help you at the beggining to understand the GitFlow.

Comment: Read [this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to improve your understanding the *Git Flow* workflow,. Also, I highly recommend [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) as git GUI frontend. It's simple, beginner friendly and supports an understanding of how git works.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things about this.

First, doing back-to-back `fetch`es (like your first two commands) would rarely make sense.  `git fetch origin` will pull down all existing branches and their history in a typical configuration, so there's normally no need to follow up with `git fetch origin *some-branch*`.

Second, at each step we have to make some assumptions to figure out if the commands you're issuing are correct.  If the branch already exists on the remote, and either it doesn't exist locally or the remote has no changes beyond what's already present in the local branch, and you're doing something to edit the working copy between the `checkout` and the `add`, then those commands are likely more or less right.  (Merge conflicts are imo more likely after the last merge command, rather than after pulling dev, if you're using the branches in a typical way.)